# Node AWS SDK - wait for SQS message

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js

I am using official Node's AWS SDK and SQS module from this package

```
import { SQS } from 'aws-sdk';
```

What is the proper way of waiting for an SQS message?

My current implementation does

```
const message = await this.sqs.receiveMessage({ QueueUrl: url }).promise();
```

And I thought it would await until new message enters the queue but it doesn't work like that. It actually just returns object which does not contain `Messages` key when there are no messages in queue.

My idea is to implement an interval and send this request every second or so but it seems like re-inventing the wheel.

What is the proper way of receiving messages from such queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Node.js library called `sqs-consumer` it is widely used.